# List categories with count for each item

Tags: php, mysql

I have  categories currently in my HTML code as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li>Category 1: ($Count)</li>
    <li>Category 2: ($Count)</li>
    <li>Category 3: ($Count)</li>
</ul>
```

I want list the count of number of elements each category contain. i could get the count a of category using following SQL syntax:

```
SELECT COUNT(element) FROM category WHERE cid = 1
```

However, I don't know how to bind this up to each category in the HTML code.

I can only think of one other way of implementing this: make the category name dynamic by storing it also in the database, then select all the categories with count.

Comment: How is category related to $Count . Is cid = 1 for Category 1 and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you it will be better if you could store category name in database. If you store Category name in database like

```
categories
+----+----------------------+
 cid | cat_name                 |
+----+----------------------+
| 1  | Category 1
| 2  | Category 2
| 3  | Category 3
...
```

Then you could query database like:

```
$query = "SELECT count(*) as count,`cat_name` FROM categories GROUP BY cid";


<ul>
   <?php foreach($categories as $category) { // Or however you get it ?>
      <li><?php echo htmlentities($category['cat_name']); ?>: (<?php echo $category['count']; ?>)</li>
  <?php } ?>
 </ul>
```

If you don't store the Category Name in db, another possibility is that if your cid 1 is same as category 1 and so on then you can do.

```
$query = "SELECT count(*) as count,`cid` FROM category GROUP BY cid ORDER BY cid ASC"
```

Provided the $result is in array in order then you can do

```
<ul>
   <li>Category 1: ($result[0][count])</li>
   <li>Category 2: ($result[1][count])</li>
   <li>Category 3: ($result[2][count])</li>
</ul>
```

But i recommend you to use first one.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend just storing a list of the categories in your database. You can select the count along with your other fields, and it's more elegant. Pretty much:

```
categories
+----+----------------------+
| id | name                 |
+----+----------------------+
| 1  | Some category
...
```

and

```
elements
+-----+-----------+-------------+
| cid | blah      | blah2       |
+-----+-----------+-------------+
|  1  | something | whatever    |
...
```

and query:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(SELECT * FROM elements WHERE elements.cid = categories.id) AS count
FROM categories
```

and display:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($results as $category) { // Or however you get it ?>
    <li><?php echo htmlentities($category['name']); ?>: <?php echo $category['count']; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) operator

```
SELECT COUNT(element) FROM category GROUP BY cid
```